# Calabash-android executes iphone simulator

Tags: android, testing, cucumber, cross-platform, calabash

I've created cross-platform test using calabash. When I try to test android app I launch:
    calabash-android run  -p android

but calabash tries to run it in phone-simulator. I see iPhone simulator restarting all over again and an error in the console
     undefined local variable or method `uninstall_apps' for # (NameError)

Also, when I check processes i see there is 
    /System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -S cucumber -p android MAIN_ACTIVITY= TEST_APP_PATH= APP_PATH=

iOS tests runs fine, also when I move pages/steps definitions/support files to separate directory, same calabash-android command executes them fine.

So, do you have an idea where can I have an error? I have cucumber.yml set up correctly in config directory.

Answer (score 2):

I added env.rb in common support directory with

```
if ENV['PLATFORM'] == 'ios'
require 'calabash-cucumber/cucumber'
elsif ENV['PLATFORM'] == 'android'
require 'calabash-android/cucumber'
end

class RunState
@@first_run = true
def self.run!
@@first_run = false
end
def self.first_run?
@@first_run
end
end
```

works